# Xcode Timer Speed Issue

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)startTrip:(id)sender {
    MainInt = 0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                             target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(countup) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];
}
```

Basically, it's a counter that counts up every 1 second. It displays the time and it works. Until this IBAction happens again, where it's supposed to reset to 0 and start counting again. It does reset but it starts counting super fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invalidate existing timer before starting it again. I assume `timer` declared globally.

```
- (IBAction)startTrip:(id)sender {
    MainInt = 0;

    if (timer.isValid) {
        [timer invalidate]; // here if timer is valid invalidate first.
    }

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                             target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(countup) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];
}
```